# can I separately control the x and y axes using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a ggplot from the [ggplot wiki](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Axis-Attributes):

```
baseplot <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
baseplot
```

[image]

### Question

Is it possible to control these axes separately, e.g. to make only the x-axis black? It does not appear that `axis.line.x` and `axis.line.y` are among the options.

### What I have tried

1. The wiki demonstrates that, e.g., it is possible to control the color of the axis

   ```
   baseplot + opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = 'black', size = 2))
   ```

   [image]
2. using `geom_segment` works but has the limitation that the lines have to be matched to the plot numbers.

   Is there a way to get, e.g. the axis max and min and ticks from the `baseplot` object? That would reduce potential bugs. *update* the answer to this question, "no, not yet", was covered [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6501538/199217).

   ```
   baseplot + geom_segment(aes(x = c(0,0), y = c(0,0), 
                           yend = c(0, max(y)), xend = c(max(x), 0), 
                           size = c(0.5, 0.1))) + 
              geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = y, 
                           xend = -1, 
                           yend = y, 
                           size = 0.1))
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can also achieve it easily by adapting a theme thusly:

```
mytheme <- theme_classic()
mytheme$axis.line.x <- mytheme$axis.line.y <- mytheme$axis.line
mytheme$axis.line.x$colour <- 'red'
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + mytheme
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It is not supported to control axis line separately.
You can remove or edit the line after drawing:

```
> baseplot + opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = 'black', size = 2))
> grid.remove(gPath("axis_v", "axis.line.segments"), grep=TRUE)

> baseplot + opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = 'black', size = 2))
> grid.edit(gPath("axis_v", "axis.line.segments"), grep=TRUE, gp=gpar(col="red"))
> grid.edit(gPath("axis_h", "axis.line.segments"), grep=TRUE, gp=gpar(col="blue"))
```

**UPDATED**

In 0.9.1-, this may change like:

```
grid.edit(gPath("axis-l", "axis.line.segments"), grep=TRUE, gp=gpar(col="red"))
grid.edit(gPath("axis-b", "axis.line.segments"), grep=TRUE, gp=gpar(col="blue"))
```

Comment: @kohske that works very nicely, but is there a way that I can assign the new graph to an object? e.g., so that I can just call `baseplot` and it will plot the edited plot?

Comment: @kohske I cannot get this to work in ggplot 0.9.0. Has there been a change between the ggplot2 versions?

Comment: @Misha in 0.9.1? Here is the slight modification. see update.

Comment: @kohske That worked wonders. Thx a million. If I could somehow accept your answer I would.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are correct in your analysis.

However, there is one other potential workaround: `geom_hline` and `geom_vline`:

```
baseplot + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="red", size = 3) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="blue", size = 2)
```

Again not ideal, since the lines span the entire plot area rather than just framing the axis, if you know what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue points out that you can turn on both lines and then turn off one of them: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/778.  I found this strategy to be both simple and effective.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. The issue you link to seems to be a request for such a feature / identification of the expected behavior that you suggest. However, the issue was closed and there are no plans for this behavior to be implemented.