# remove only y axis using axis.line in ggplot2 0.9.0

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can I separately control the x and y axes using ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541329/can-i-separately-control-the-x-and-y-axes-using-ggplot)

I saw an earlier post describing how to do this ([can I separately control the x and y axes using ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541329/can-i-separately-control-the-x-and-y-axes-using-ggplot))-but it doesn´t work in ggplot 0.9.0. Any ideas how I can remove only the y-axis line, and not the x axis line. The axis.line option does not allow any differenatiation between the two axes.

```
 u<-expand.grid(temp=seq(0,100,10),hum=c(20,90),delta=as.factor(seq(0,10,by=5)))

u$model<-exp(u$temp*log(0.88)+u$hum*log(1.01)+as.numeric(u$delta)*log(1.1)) 
u2<-subset(u,hum==20)

u4<-subset(u,hum==90)
pl<-ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=u2,aes(x=u2$temp,y=u2$model,colour=u2$delta,group=u2$delta))+
  geom_line(data=u4,aes(x=temp,y=model,colour=delta,group=delta))

pl+theme_bw()+
  opts(panel.grid.minor=theme_blank(),
       panel.grid.major=theme_blank(),
       legend.key=theme_blank(),
       panel.border=theme_rect(colour=NA),
       axis.line=theme_segment(colour='grey',size=1))
```

Now -  how can I just have the x-axis and not the y-axis line?

The earlier post recommended

```
grid.remove(gPath("axis_v", "axis.line.segments"), grep=TRUE)
```

resulting in

> Error in removeDLFromGPath(gPath, name, strict, greppath, grepname,
>   global,  :    gPath (axis_v::axis.line.segments) not found

//M

Comment: see the update in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work-around that may help. Set the plotting limits strictly with `coord_cartesian()` and then add x-axis line manually. It shouldn't be too hard to calculate the y-axis range programmatically.

```
opts(axis.line=theme_blank()) +
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-0.05, 3.3)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept=-0.05, colour="grey", size=1.5)
```