# How to remove y.axis panel border?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my code

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
  geom_point() + theme_clean()
```

I want to remove the y-axis black line. This is my desired results 
[image]

Best,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can I separately control the x and y axes using ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541329/can-i-separately-control-the-x-and-y-axes-using-ggplot)

Comment: Which black line are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the folowing code

```
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
  geom_point() + theme_hc() + 
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line())
```

[image]

If you want to have an answer according to your code then

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_clean()+
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line(), plot.background=element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this (using `theme_classic`, which is kind of close to your desired result, but has both x and y axis lines present):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
    geom_point() + theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line())
```

[image]

If you type `theme_classic` (no parenthesese), you can see all the `theme` elements that are used to create that theme.  Note that the classic theme has `axis.line` applied, which creates both x and y axis lines.  If you try *only* specifying `axix.line.y = element_blank()`, it does not work, since `theme_classic()` applies `axis.line` back over that command - resulting in both lines again.  This is why you have to specify *both* here.