# breaks at integer powers of ten on ggplot2 log10 axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Transforming `ggplot2` axes to log10 using `scales::trans_breaks()` can sometimes (if the range is small enough) produce *un-pretty* breaks, at non-integer powers of ten.

Is there a general purpose way of setting these breaks to occur only at 10^x, where x are all integers, and, ideally, consecutive (e.g. 10^1, 10^2, 10^3)?

Here's an example of what I mean.

```
library(ggplot2)

# dummy data
df <- data.frame(fct = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
                 x = rep(1:3, 3),
                 y = 10^seq(from = -4, to = 1, length.out = 9))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ fct, scales = "free_y") # faceted to try and emphasise that it's general purpose, rather than specific to a particular axis range
```

The unwanted result -- y-axis breaks are at non-integer powers of ten (e.g. 10^2.8)

```
p + scale_y_log10(
    breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
    labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))
  )
```

[image]

I can achieve the desired result for this particular example by adjusting the `n` argument to `scales::trans_breaks()`, as below. But this is not a general purpose solution, of the kind that could be applied without needing to adjust anything on a case-by-case basis.

```
p + scale_y_log10(
    breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n = 1),
    labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))
  )
```

[image]

Should add that I'm not wed to using `scales::trans_breaks()`, it's just that I've found it's the function that gets me closest to what I'm after.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: maybe helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/q/5380417/7941188

Comment: maybe also helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622001/how-to-display-only-integer-values-on-an-axis-using-ggplot2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach that at the core has the following function.

```
breaks = function(x) {
    brks <- extended_breaks(Q = c(1, 5))(log10(x))
    10^(brks[brks %% 1 == 0])
}
```

It gives `extended_breaks()` a narrow set of 'nice numbers' and then filters out non-integers.

This gives us the following for you example case:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
#> Warning: package 'scales' was built under R version 4.0.3

# dummy data
df <- data.frame(fct = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
                 x = rep(1:3, 3),
                 y = 10^seq(from = -4, to = 1, length.out = 9))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ fct, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = "log10",
    breaks = function(x) {
      brks <- extended_breaks(Q = c(1, 5))(log10(x))
      10^(brks[brks %% 1 == 0])
    },
    labels = math_format(format = log10)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I haven't tested this on many other ranges that might be difficult, but it should generalise better than setting the number of desired breaks to 1. Difficult ranges might be those just in between -but not including- powers of 10. For example 11-99 or 101-999.

Comment: instead of `scale_y_continuous(trans = "log",...)` you can also use `scale_y_log10` +1

Comment: That's right, I'm just in the habit of being verbose in this way (so that I can just change a parameter instead of a function when exploring data).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @teunbrand, that's excellent. Would you mind please explaining effect the `Q` argument has on `extended_breaks()` in this context? I've tried playing around with it, but it's not clear to me what it does. Just trying to understand your solution better :)

Comment: The `Q` argument gets passed on to `labeling::extended` and it is a set of numbers that the break algorithm considers 'nice', i.e. it chooses those types of numbers. By default, this is 1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4 and 5, I think. Because it won't accept a length 1 `Q`, I had to pass it a second number too. Later I filter for multiples of 1 (`%% 1 == 0`), so it doesn't matter really what the second number is.

Comment: Nice solution, @teunbrand. I'm trying to use it in a function that uses egg::ggarrange at the end, so I'd like to use your solution several times as a function within a function, but I'm having trouble; I can't seem to pass the necessary info into it when I call it in the scale_y_continuous function. Any suggestions?

Comment: @teunbrand, I've just found out that you can pass the same "nice number" twice to `labeling::extended()` to force it to use your preferred one. It won't complain. So, in this example, you could call `extended_breaks(Q = c(1, 1))` and use the result right away.