# How do I get a more logical scale bar?

Tags: r, gis

I've plotted point data of parakeet observations (fake for now) across the UK with the observations coloured by the population density of the area the observation was made in. I have a continuous scale bar as I want but the scale itself is awkwardly annotated. How can I plot it with more even dividers?

Here is the code:

############################
#PLOT OBSERVATIONS x POP_DENS
############################

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = UK, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill="gray14", alpha=0.7) +
  geom_point(data=paratweets_4, aes(x=coords.x1, y=coords.x2, color=pop_dens, shape=Occupancy), size=2,stroke=FALSE) +
  scale_color_viridis(option="magma", trans="log", name="Human Population Density (km2)") +
  theme_minimal() + ylim(50,59) + coord_map() + 
  ggtitle("Parakeet Observations")
```

Here is the map:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy would be to make a column for the scale bar, with a metric that makes sense to you. For example,

```
df %>% 
  mutate(scale_column = case_when(
    pop_dens == 0 ~ "0",
    pop_dens > 0 & pop_dens < 100 ~ "0-100",
    pop_dens > 100 & pop_dens < 1000 ~ "100-999",
    pop_dens > 1000 & pop_dens < 2000 ~ "1000-1999",
  ))
```

Then using that column as your scale.
Another option would be to modify the [breaks of the scales.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380417/is-there-a-way-of-manipulating-ggplot-scale-breaks-and-labels)
However, I would argue that in this case it might make sense to not have scale by color, but rather change the `size` of the points.